# Parar todos os serviços no Azure

Tags: microsoft-azure

Tenho vários serviços em alguns Grupos de Recursos no Azure, hoje tenho que parar um por um quando necessário! É possível parar todos de uma só vez?

Answer (score 1):

Não, não tem essa funcionalidade da forma como procura. Isso pq não é todo serviço que possui a opção "Stop". A única coisa que se pode fazer em lote é excluir todo um *Resouce Group* - o que já ajuda muito.

Mas, vc pode usar o Azure bash com CLI para fazer isso bem simples. Segue exemplo de como iniciar, parar e desalocar VMs.

```
# example usage
az vm start --ids $(
    az vm list --query "[].id"
        -o tsv | grep "Test"
)

az vm stop --ids $(
    az vm list --query "[].id"
        -o tsv | grep "Test"
)

az vm deallocate --ids $(
    az vm list --query "[].id"
        -o tsv | grep "Test"
)
```

Fonte: https://buildazure.com/2017/06/07/azure-cli-2-0-quickly-start-stop-all-vms/

Comment: É possível fazer o mesmo esquema que você fez com VM para Web App's?

Comment: Nao, pois o comando `az webapp stop` nao aceita array de `ids`. Mas confesso que não vejo muito sentido nisso, pq vc pararia todas as webapps de um resource group?

Comment: quero parar todos os serviços porque já chegou no meu limite de crédito e não quero deixar ligado, mas dai você fala, o Azure tem uma trava para isso, sim, tem. Mas eu tirei a trava pois quero testar meu APP depois desligar tudo, depois ligar tudo novamente quando for testar, entendeu?

Comment: eu só queria uma forma de desligar tudo enquanto não estiver utilizando para não ficar contabilizando.

Comment: WebApp não para de contabilizar, mesmo parados.

Comment: entendi, se eu parar as VM's pelo menos para de contabilizar? Neste comando acima eu não perco elas não né? Pelo que percebo os webapp's não gastam muito, mas as VM's parece que sim.

Comment: Parar VM só contabiliza storage, mas hora computação não.